# Modifying installed apps permissions (Android)

Tags: java, android, permissions

I want to develop an application for android to:

1. List installed applications in the phone.
2. Show a list of permissions that are granted for each app.
3. Have the ability to disable any permission granted to a specific app or enable it later on.

Till now I have done the first two points. I searched the web to know how to modify permissions but I couldn't find anything useful.

So can anybody give me a clue on how to implement this ? Because I think it is doable since there some apps that can modify permissions (e.g. Permission Manager).

Comment: I'd recommend you check out this https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_external_proguard
It's Proguard from CyanogenMod Roms, it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are various apps in the Play Store that call themselves Permission Manager so I'm not sure which one you have looked at.

At least one of them works by pulling the installed app apart, and reforming it with a changed AndroidManifest file (and since they don't have access to the original private key, a new signature).  To run the reformed app you have to uninstall the old one, and install the new one, which has 2 significant downsides

- all the data of the old app is lost
- since you now have an effective pirate version of the app, the app will no longer update with new versions from the Play Store.

Other apps that claim to manage app permissions simply expose the hidden App Ops permission screen in Android 4.3, and Google removed this from the later Android 4.4 update.